# How to detect a specific USB device and write data to it out of Linux Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, usb

Since every answers given to similar topics are outdated I'd like to know if there is a prevailing way to detect if an USB stick is connected or not?
I already checked the DBus module but didn't find any useful tutorial/example. Same with udev.

I'm planning on a "simple" GUI with buttons for the detection and for writing data on the device.
Would DBus be the best choice for my purpose?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Michael